# "Python exec is not exist" when creating new project in Cocos Studio

Tags: android, python, cocos2d-x, game-engine, cocostudio

I've just started with Cocos2D gaming engine. I was following the official documentation to setup my machine for the development. Everything went smoothly, but when I tried to create a new project, it fails with an error message stating

> Python exec is not exist

I'm not sure if I understand this. I tried searching the problem on the Internet but the only place I found relevant questions were on Chinese forums where the translate option doesn't help much.

- How do I resolve this issue?

**EDIT**

I followed the steps described in below link under section Appendix B, Which describes the entire setup of cocos2D-x.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/B/index.html

Then I downloaded Cocos Studio to start on development. Clicked *file->New Project* as shown in the figure. And, upon clicking *finish* I get the described error (See the screenshot).

[image]

Comment: Could you please say what you do **exactly**? Step by step. And where does the error originate?

Comment: @AleksanderLidtke Added the screenshot and some more information

Comment: No one has answer for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also experienced the same problem but found no direct solution. However, there exist a workaround.

The GUI tools provided in Cocos Studio are very unpredictable and should not be trusted. The application crushed randomly, fails to create projects without proper warnings or debug messages and so on. So here is what do to:

**To create new projects, drop to command line** and use the `cocos new` command. I assume you can set all the environment variable to make this process as painless as possible.

```
cocos new -h
```

will give all the info. For example, to create a new c++ project called AwesomeGame at a folder `C:\Projects\AwesomeGame`, you can type:

```
cocos new -l cpp -d c:\projects\AwesomeGame -p com.gamestudio.AwesomeGame AwesomeGame
```

**After creating the project via `cocos new`**, you can now open Cocos Studio to edit your Scenes, Nodes, Animations, Sprites and all the usual stuff. You will never meet the

> "Python exec is not exist" error.

Comment: Before trying your solution, I tried re-installing cocos studio, and surprisingly it worked. I didn't had to download a new installer as well. Strange, but your solution works as well.